# Как запустить одновременную работу отправки сообщений по таймеру и оставить рабочими запросы вручную и изменение локации?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть телеграм-бот, к которому я стараюсь привязать отправку погоды по таймеру. Отдельно по таймеру оно работает, так же как и отдельно посылает запросы на погоду вручную типо "какая погода прям сейчас". Возникла проблема - связать оба процесса, то есть дело пахнет многопоточностью, как я понял. Нашел вариант - использовать schedule и столкнулся со следующей проблемой: после установки времени таймера, я остаюсь в функции с отправкой сообщений по таймеру, то есть вручную все функции отваливаются.

Вот код для ознакомления:

```html
def set_time(message): #Функция с запуском таймера и отправкой сообщения погоды
    timer = message.text
    schedule.every().day.at(timer).do(timer_alert, message)
    nowTime = datetime.now()
    print ('%s' % nowTime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"), "// Set timer at: ", timer)
    process_step(message)
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()

def timer_alert(message): #Сообщение по таймеру
    nowTime = datetime.now()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Погода пришла!')
    print ('%s' % nowTime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"), '// Send weather timer message')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['location']) #обработка локации
def handle_location(message):
    nowTime = datetime.now()
    lat = message.location.latitude
    lng = message.location.longitude
    bot.reply_to(message, '%s\n%s' % (lat, lng))
    send_alltime(message)
    global forecast
    forecast = forecastio.load_forecast(api_key, lat, lng, time=datetime.now(), units="si")
    print ('%s' % nowTime.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"), '// Set location message')
```

Собственно вопрос - как запустить одновременную работу отправки сообщений по таймеру и оставить рабочими запросы вручную и изменение локации.

Answer (score 1):

Если время отправки погоды фиксированное, то можно вынести часть кода в отдельный скрипт, где не будет получения сообщений, только отправка и завершение работы, и поставить этот скрипт в системный планировщик `cron`.

Приём сообщений возможен только в одном "приложении", а отправка может быть откуда угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал вот так:

```
# pip3 install pytelegrambotapi
import telebot
from multiprocessing import Process

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

# так мы обрабатываем команды
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Commands: /subscribe /unsubscribe /check /help')

# это функция отправки сообщений по таймеру     
def check_send_messages():
    while True:
        # ваш код проверки времени и отправки сообщений по таймеру
        # пауза между проверками, чтобы не загружать процессор
        time.sleep(60)

# а теперь запускаем проверку в отдельном потоке
p1 = Process(target=check_send_messages, args=())
p1.start()

# а это включение бота на прием сообщений
# обернуто в try, потому что если Telegram сервер станет недоступен, возможен крэш
while True:
    try:
        bot.polling(none_stop=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        # повторяем через 15 секунд в случае недоступности сервера Telegram
        time.sleep(15)
```